# How to average values in plot, to make a plot with fewer values

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a script that plots wind speed in m/s (measured every second) against time in minutes over a period of 24 hours. I want to make a new plot that instead of plotting wind speed each second, averages the wind speed over a period of 10 minutes and then plots this against the time.

Here is a sample image of my data:

[image: sample data]

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Comment: do you have the curvefitting toolbox? than you can use `smooth` to achieve [Moving Average Filtering](http://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Moving Average filter using the [`smooth`](http://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html) function as suggested by m.s. in a comment. This is fairly simple:

```
y = smooth(x,span);
```

This uses a symmetric smoothing filter, so the span (i.e. the number of samples it takes for smoothing) must be odd: take the current sample plus `n` before and `n` after the current sample. That way you still have one sample for every second, they are just smoothed to damp noise and measurement errors.

If you want to reduce the number of points, such that only one point every 10 minutes exists, you can do the following: You take the first `10min * 60s = 600` samples of the vector and put them in the first column of a new matrix. Then take the next 600 samples and put them in the second column, and so on. Now you can column-wise take the mean of the matrix. That way you have a new vector where every element is the mean of 600 samples.

In MATLAB this is easily possible:

```
X = reshape(x,600,[]);    % create matrix with 600 elements per column
y = mean(X,1);            % take column-wise mean
```